# how to a translatable string in drupal theme?

Tags: theming, 6, i18n-l10n

I want to put a string as a signature in drupal theme I am working on. the website is multilingual and the string should be translated based on the current language of the website. I don't know how to do it.

my drupal version is 6.

Would you help me?

Answer (score 4):

The first step to translate a string used from a module, or a theme is using [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/t/6) for every string that needs to be translated. Remember that the first argument given to the function is a literal string containing a phrase in English. This means that the following calls to `t()` are not correct.

```
// The string is a concatenation of literal strings.
$error = t('This example, ' . "doesn't work.");
```

```
// Also in this case there is a concatenation of literal strings.
$errno = 15;
$error = t("Error number $errno received while translating a string.");
```

```
// This could work, provided that another function calls t() using a
// literal string that is equal to the string returned from the function.
$error = t(mymodule_get_error());
```

The second step is providing the translation of the string passed to `t()`. If the theme is hosted on Drupal.org, then the translation will be provided from translators on http://localize.drupal.org.
Otherwise, you need to translate the string on admin/build/translate/search.

You can look for the string to translate searching for untranslated strings, or entering a string.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't filter by strings in your theme. It bundles those strings with Drupal core strings so that you're stuck with a bloated list of strings that you would normally want to export to a translator.

Answer (score -1):

you should use something like t('your string');